# why doesn't my emitter emit particles anymore normally?

Tags: animation-nodes

I want to move my emitter but when i plug in my nodes as in the picture below, the emitter emits just for a frame or so, not the whole frames. What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parent emitter to an empty object and try animating empty using animation nodes.

or

Bake AN animation using `Set Keyframes` Node

Comment: thank you. Parenting helped! Although i don't know why ;)